# how to stop the service of one application while we are using another application in android

Tags: java, android

In My Application I am running the service  its working fine,but the problem is 
when I open any application like whats app,face book etc .. again My service started freshly how to overcome this problem

This is My Code Guys:

```
public class GpsTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    Intent intent1;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    public double latitude, longitude;
    String Lat,Log,stringFromFragment,add,time;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    DBHelper dbh;
    StringBuilder strReturnedAddress;
    StausEventDao stausEventDao;
    Context context;
    int minutes=15*60000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        intent1 = new Intent("com.ds.service");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Starting Tracker", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 900000, 1, this);
        } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 900000, 1, this);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enable gps to get location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        if(intent !=null) {
            stringFromFragment = intent.getStringExtra("STATUS");
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

       /* if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 1, this);
        } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 1, this);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enable gps to get location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        context=getApplicationContext();



        Lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
        Log = String.valueOf(longitude);
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

            if (addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(1)).append("\n");
                add = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Cannot get Address! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        dbh = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        dbh.getReadableDatabase();

        stausEventDao=new StatusEventImpDao(context);
        stausEventDao.saveStatusEventChange(latitude,longitude,add,time,stringFromFragment);
        String values=stausEventDao.getValues(latitude,longitude,add,time,stringFromFragment);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),values,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        intent1.putExtra("LATITUDE", latitude);
        intent1.putExtra("LONGITUDE", longitude);
        intent1.putExtra("ADDRESS", add);
        sendBroadcast(intent1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public class TrackerBinder extends Binder {
        public GpsTracker getService() {
            return GpsTracker.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If starting another app results in your service "restarting" then it's probably a memory/resource issue... in other words, those other apps consume resources to the extent that yours is killed, then restarted after the startup of those apps is complete or allows for yours to resume.

You basically have two options:

1. reduce the resources your app consumes while running in order to prevent this (which is very difficult and will vary from device to device). This approach, however, will ensure continuous operation of your service. But it requires you to reduce or alter the substance of your data collection/processing.
2. persist the data that you need to persist or retain frequently, and also track the time that your service is "down" before it restarts so you can collect as much data as possible. You can also try to measure the resources used, memory consumption, etc. that results in the restart, but doing so will likely shut down your service faster. That still might be helpful in developing the parameters for optimal operation of your service.

Other apps cannot stop yours. You must work within the constraints of the system. Once you recognize that, your approach to the "problem" will be redefined. These other apps probably consume a lot of resources, especially on older devices, but regardless that is the problem you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Usually onStartCommand is responsible for restarting the service, try returning START_NOT_STICKY that should keep the service from restarting.

```
  @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        if(intent !=null) {
            stringFromFragment = intent.getStringExtra("STATUS");
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: I am Using this START_NOT_STICKY; its working but when i open My application again from the service its open freshly